# Stop a while with nullptr in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I try to use nullptr in a while, if is the null pointer stop while.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
  int count = 0;
  while(p)
  {
    if (*p==x)
      ++count;
    ++p;
  }
  return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *arr = "aabbaa";
  char s = 'a';
  cout << count_x(arr, s) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but with this code, When I execute I get this message

```
Bus error: 10
```

I compile with this line

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o count_x count_x.cpp
```

Comment: the condition should be `*p != '\0'`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thanks with `*p != '\0'` the code works, and works too with `*p != nullptr`

Comment: Change `while (p)` to `while (*p)`.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks this is the solution, maybe you can post like a answers to close the question

Comment: @JuanPablo `*p` is not a pointer, you should not compare it to `nullptr`

Comment: The code written like this (corrected to check for 0-character instead of nullptr) is still brittle, because it assumes that a null-terminated string is passed.  This is a convention in C, which can also be used in C++, but there are better alternatives (std::string, std::count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is zero-terminated, which means, that its last byte is 0. If you increase the pointer, you need to check for the pointer *pointing* to 0, not *beeing* 0.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*p)
    {
        if (*p == x)
            ++count;
        ++p;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *arr = "aabbaa";
    char s = 'a';
    cout << count_x(arr, s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `while(p)`, you are going to run for a very long time (or more likely, perform a memory access violation and generate a segmentation fault much sooner than that).

Putting that aside, the formal description is that `*p == x` will generate undefined behavior once `p` points outside the memory boundaries of the string that it initially points to.

Long story short, change `while (p)` to `while (*p)`, or simply do:

```
for (int i=0; p[i]; i++)
{
    if (p[i] == x)
        ++count;
}
```